# Prius 2010 oil reset (Europe edition not US edition)

Tags: oil-change

All,

I have 2010 prius that has Europe standards (Kilometer odometer) not mile, and it doesn't have the button "Mpg/KL" to reset the oil change light.

How does it work for such edition? is it the saem way of the US edition? I tried US edition by pressing on "trip" button instead, but didn't work.

Any help, please?

Thanks
Basil

Answer (score 1):

From memory, this requires a trip to a mechanic who can reset the code using an ODBII scanner and specialist software.